# Remove duplicate element parent name in MarkLogic Javascript

Tags: javascript, marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am working on harmonizing data in MarkLogic using javascript. Currently, for my output, I am able to display all the child elements `Activity` but the problem is the parent `Activities` is also being displayed in duplicate.

Here is the current output, where `<Activities>` only appear for every `Activity`:

```html
<Activities datatype="array">
 <Activity>
   <ActivityCrewSize>10</ActivityCrewSize>
   <ActivitySeqNo>1</ActivitySeqNo>
   <ActivityDesc/>
 </Activity>
</Activities>
<Activities datatype="array">
 <Activity>
   <ActivityCrewSize>23</ActivityCrewSize>
   <ActivitySeqNo>2</ActivitySeqNo>
   <ActivityDesc/>
 </Activity>
</Activities>
<Activities datatype="array">
 <Activity>
   <ActivityCrewSize>50</ActivityCrewSize>
   <ActivitySeqNo>3</ActivitySeqNo>
   <ActivityDesc/>
 </Activity>
</Activities>
```

And here is my desired output, where `<Activities>` only appear once

```html
<Activities datatype="array">
 <Activity>
   <ActivityCrewSize>10</ActivityCrewSize>
   <ActivitySeqNo>1</ActivitySeqNo>
   <ActivityDesc/>
 </Activity>
 <Activity>
   <ActivityCrewSize>23</ActivityCrewSize>
   <ActivitySeqNo>2</ActivitySeqNo>
   <ActivityDesc/>
 </Activity>
 <Activity>
   <ActivityCrewSize>50</ActivityCrewSize>
   <ActivitySeqNo>3</ActivitySeqNo>
   <ActivityDesc/>
 </Activity>
</Activities>
```

Below is my current code for the current output:

```js
obj.Activities = [];

let act = {
    '$type': 'Activity',
    '$version': '0.0.1',
     } 
  
for (const item of activities) {

 act.ActivityCrewSize = fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "CrewSize", true)); 
 act.ActivitySeqNo = fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "SeqNo", true)); 
 act.ActivityDesc = hl.elementText(item, null, true);

 obj.Activities.push(act); 
}

return obj;
```

Comment: if you could provide a bit of sample data and extend your code to show how these JSON objects are being converted to XML, it would be a lot easier to help with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Javascript guy, but if you wrap your input with another root element and then run the following xquery code on Qconsole, you will get the desired result that you want.

`

```
let $doc := <acts>
<Activities datatype="array">
    <Activity>
      <ActivityCrewSize>10</ActivityCrewSize>
      <ActivitySeqNo>1</ActivitySeqNo>
      <ActivityDesc/>
    </Activity>
</Activities>
<Activities datatype="array">
    <Activity>
      <ActivityCrewSize>23</ActivityCrewSize>
      <ActivitySeqNo>2</ActivitySeqNo>
      <ActivityDesc/>
    </Activity>
</Activities>
<Activities datatype="array">
    <Activity>
      <ActivityCrewSize>50</ActivityCrewSize>
      <ActivitySeqNo>3</ActivitySeqNo>
      <ActivityDesc/>
    </Activity>
</Activities>
</acts>
return 
<Activities datatype="array">
{
for $each in $doc/Activities/Activity
return $each
}
```

`

Comment: Thanks for the response but the solution should be in javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you create a separate JavaScript object for each item, does that produce the desired result?

Something along the lines of:

```
obj.Activities = [];

for (const item of activities) {
    obj.Activities.push({
    '$type': 'Activity',
    '$version': '0.0.1',
    ActivityCrewSize: fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "CrewSize", true)),
    ActivitySeqNo, fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "SeqNo", true)),
    ActivityDesc: hl.elementText(item, null, true)
     });
}

return obj;
```

Alternatively, NodeBuilder can construct the XML directly:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/api#id_90865

Comment: Hi @ehennum, thanks for your response. I tried this suggestion but  parent Activities is still displayed in duplicate.

Comment: As Dave Casell suggested, maybe the next step is to revise the question to show how you're transforming the JSON to XML.